# CSS Caret beside active link in vertical scolling sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got the following html

```
<aside class="SideNavLayoutWrapper">
  <div class="OverFlowWrapper">
    <div class="MenuWrapper">
      <a class="SideNavMenuItem">Link 1</a>
      <a class="SideNavMenuItem active">Link 2</a>
      <a class="SideNavMenuItem">Link 3</a>
      <a class="SideNavMenuItem">Link 4</a>
      <a class="SideNavMenuItem">Link 5</a>
      <a class="SideNavMenuItem">Link 6</a>
      <a class="SideNavMenuItem">Link 7</a>
      <a class="SideNavMenuItem">Link 8</a>
      <a class="SideNavMenuItem">Link 9</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Which is a side navigation

and the following css to go alongside the above html

```
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.SideNavLayoutWrapper {
  will-change: transform;
  width: 260px;
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 6;
  background-color: #384143;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.OverFlowWrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  z-index: unset;
  display: block;
  position: static;
  background: transparent;
}

.MenuWrapper {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  transition: transform linear 300ms;
}

.SideNavMenuItem {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 20px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  transition: color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.08, 1), background-color 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.08, 1);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px 18px 18px 0;
}

.SideNavMenuItem.active {
  color: #ee4900;
}

.SideNavMenuItem.active::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-width: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #384143;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

The issue I am having, is that when a `SideNavMenuItem` has an `active` class to dictate that it's an active link I want a caret to the right of the link.

However, while yes, it does go to the right of the link, it is hidden from the user due to the  `overflow-y: auto;` in `.OverflowWrapper`.

the  `overflow-y: auto;` is there so the user can scroll vertically, but it also scrolls horizontally now as the caret added in `.SideNavMenuItem.active::before`  extends the width of the link, but I want the caret to sit outside of the aside, which it only does when the  `overflow-y: auto;` in `.OverflowWrapper` is removed, but when I remove the  `overflow-y: auto;` then the user cannot scroll vertically.

Is there a way that I can have the caret marker align to the right of the active link and appear outside to the right of the aside but also allow the user to scroll vertically on the aside?

Is this only achievable by having the caret moved outside of `.SideNavLayoutWrapper` element and using javascript to position the caret in the correct position? Though, with that, I need to handle what happens when a user scrolls and also when the user scrolls and the link is no longer in view?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you hear about tooltip, example like [Tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/)?

Answer (score 0):

On `.SideNavLayoutWrapper` set `width:280px` and remove its background;
On `.MenuWrapper` set `width: 260px` and put the background color here.

This will make the caret appear. The only problem is that the scrollbar will appear to the right of the caret, but other solutions to that would require javascript.